# how to get a series of numbers and don't know how many is in python

Tags: python

I want to get a series of numbers but I don't know how many numbers the user want to input....and I don't want to have something like this:

```
print("please enter a number or -1 to exit")
while(int(input())!=-1):
```

or something like that:

```
print("how many numbers do you want to enter ? ")
howmany=int(input())
for i in range(howmay):
```

is there any way except these?

Comment: So what are you asking?

Comment: Simply ask the user to input the numbers as comma separated on a single line and use `import ast; numbers = ast.literal_eval(input('Enter comma-separated numbers'))`. Or `numbers = [int(token) for token in input('Enter ...').split(',')]`

Comment: When do you know that the user has finished providing their input?

Comment: getting n numbers and don't know how many is...

Comment: @PooyaFayyaz What do you mean? You do *not* want to ask the user how many numbers he wants to input? Then simply use a sentinel to signal the end of input(which can be something as simple as an empty input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about asking until user gives empty line:

```
line = raw_input()
while(line):
    # process line
    line=raw_input()
```

Or one more elegantly (from @Bakuriu's comment):

```
for line in iter(raw_input, ''):
    # process line
```

In python 3.x use `input` instead of `raw_input`.

Comment: I believe it's more elegant: `for line in iter(input, ''): #process line` since you avoid repeating yourself. (Also note that the OP seems to be using python3, where `raw_input` doesn't exist).

Comment: True, except you should use `raw_input`.

Comment: No: `>>> raw_input
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined` In python **3** you *should* use `input`.

Comment: @bakuriu and can I save users input with this method?

Comment: @PooyaFayyaz What I wrote is equivalent to the code in the solution. However I don't understand what do you mean by "save users input".

Comment: Well, this is the same as `print("please enter a number or ENTER to exit")` that the OP said he doesnt want

Comment: @joaquin How so? This doesn't require to first input number of intended inputs.

Comment: @Lycha well, to enter enter is to enter ''. It is two keystrokes shorter than to enter -1 or one keystroke shorter than enter 'e' (exit). The OP wanted not to enter anything. Maybe I was being too strict.

Answer (score 1):

One-line-solution (For Python 2.7+):

```
list(iter(lambda: input('Enter number (or -1 to finish): '), -1))
```

Using it:

```
>>> numbers = list(iter(lambda: input('Enter number (or -1 to finish): '), -1))
Enter number (or -1 to finish): 1
Enter number (or -1 to finish): 2
Enter number (or -1 to finish): 3
Enter number (or -1 to finish): 4
Enter number (or -1 to finish): -1
>>> numbers
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

---

**Note:** Using `input()` in Python 2.7+ can be unsafe as it performs an `eval()` on user input. For a safer method:

**Python 2.7+**

```
list(iter(lambda: int(raw_input('Enter number (or -1 to finish): ')), -1))
```

**Python 3.+**

```
list(iter(lambda: int(input('Enter number (or -1 to finish): ')), -1))
```

Comment: In python 2 this solution is wrong because it uses `input`, and hence it is unsafe. In python3 (which seems like what the OP is using) this solution is wrong because it uses `input`, which returns a string and hence the loop is an infinite loop.

Comment: Do you have anything constructive to say? The solution is not "wrong" it might be unwise, or unsafe, which are not concerns for everyone, this is an option of how to do this. The OP has not specified which version of Python he is using, I may have wrongfully assumed 2. If it makes *you* feel better, I will update the answer with a "safer" method and for each version.

Answer (score 1):

Some alternatives(for python *3*. In python2 replace `input` with `raw_input`):

Using a comma separated list of numbers in a single line:

```
import ast
numbers = ast.literal_eval(input('Enter comma-separated sequence of numbers'))
# or numbers = [int(el) for el in input('Enter ...').split(',')]
```

Using a space-separated sequence of numbers in a single line:

```
numbers = [int(el) for el in input('Enter ...').split()]
```

Using an empty input as sentinel, one number per line:

```
numbers = [int(el) for el in iter(input, '')]
```

Using a non-empty input sentinel, one number per line:

```
numbers = [int(el) for el in iter(input, 'END')]  #ends when user enters END.
```

Asking the number of elements

```
numbers = [int(input()) for _ in range(input('Number of elements'))]
```

Input from file(with shell redirection)/using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> as end marker, one number per line:

```
import sys
text = sys.stdin.read()
numbers = [int(el) for el in text.splitlines()]
```

If you replace `splitlines()` with `split()` then the user can put the numbers either on the same line or on multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the user gives you only `int`s:

```
howMany = int(raw_input("How many numbers would you like to add?: "))
numbers = []
for i in range(1,howMany+1):
  numbers.append(int(raw_input("Please enter the %d-th number: " %i)))
```

Alternatively:

```
numbers = [int(i) for i in raw_input("Please enter all your numbers, separated by spaces: ").split()]
```